# Silverlight 4, mvvm and the toolkit busy indicator is not working

Tags: silverlight

I must be missing a step here.

```
 <toolkit:BusyIndicator HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="busyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding BusyIndicator}">
    <Grid Background="#FFE6F0FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
```

I have the following in my viewmodel:

```
 private BusyIndicator _busyIndicator;
    public BusyIndicator BusyIndicator
    {
        get { return _busyIndicator; }
        set
        {
            if (_busyIndicator == value) return;
            _busyIndicator = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("BusyIndicator");
        }
    }

 BusyIndicator = new BusyIndicator { IsBusy = true, BusyContent = "Please wait..." };
```

But when I fire my async call to WCF, nothing shows up at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does the property return a `BusyIndicator`? Shouldn't it be a bool? Then I think it should work.

Comment: Totally overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the busy indicator on silver light page as well as on master page. this can be done using Messaging toolkit for details visit the link

http://codenicely.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-busy-indicator-of-master-page.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure the DataContext property is set for the BusyIndicator control and that the "IsBusy" property in the ViewModel is within the specified data context.  If the data context is set to a grid contained within the BusyIndicator, the property in the ViewModel won't be called.

The data context can be set at runtime (in the xaml.cs code-behind) or in the XAML.